# SQL - Join/Select on specific values

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I just have a quick simple question about SQL joins. I want to make a join or a select that will consider two columns.

For example:

.#A has emails I don't want with their respective companies.

.#B has emails I do want with their respective companies.

I wanted to select all from #B that does not have an email in #A, so my code was originally:

```
select * from #B where email not in (select email from #A)
```

But my only issue is that each email can have more than 1 company attached to it, so I want to make a select that will bring in emails in #B that are not in #A but I want the email-company combo to match. So if email-company1 does exist in #A and email-company2 does not exist in #A I don't want all related to that email not show because one of the email-company combos exist in #A.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Edit:
I apologize for the vague mention about the companies. What I meant was that #A  and #B both have columns email and company, but each email could associate itself with different companies, so when I do a select to not include emails from #A I only want to not include the emails that also match the company. So if #B has email-company2 and #A has email-company3 I don't want my select to remove email-company2 from the select statement.

I'm also aware that my question may sound a little stupid, I apologize. I'm still getting used to SQL, and I appreciate all the help and back-ups I have gotten thus far :)

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. We need some actual details here to help. Just a vague description of the problem is not going to work out well. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @jarlh ha - you should link to this with your comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/361481#361481

Comment: @All downvoting a new user is sad. Give them a break.

Comment: Don't tell us about companies in text, give us the table definition and some sample data (just a few rows)

Comment: I know this was already stated, but some sample data and an expected result would be more than helpful in getting your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
select email from b
where not exists 
(select 1 from a where b.email = a.email and b.company = a.company)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I never used a 'where not exists' before so learning something new everyday haha!

Comment: You are welcome! If this is the correct answer, please accept it by clicking the check. Thanks.